# Allow google bot crawl in firebase with app check enabled

Tags: angular, firebase, indexing, bots, recaptcha

i made an angular web app with a **firebase** backend.
I want to **allow** the google **user agent to crawl my website** so it can get **indexed**.
The problem is that since i have **App Check enabled**, all requests that are not coming from my website are blocked. **So crawling doesn't work anymore**.
My web app is too far in developpement to change it to server sided rendering (as far as i understood how server sided redering works) and i really don't want to disable app check since i already got attacked before with 2 Million requests.